# TerminateProcess doesnt work for verified process id

Tags: c++, windows

I am working on application that is supposed to kill a process with a given name.
Operating system I use is windows 7.  The thing is that for all processes listed in task manager with a non-blank USER NAME field it works fine. However when a process has an empty username cannot be killed even by task manager.

Can anyone tell me why some processes has no user name. In my case it is csrss.exe winlogon.exe and unfortunately an old application I want to have killed. All other processes I examined has a proper username.

Is there any way to add a username to existing process ?

Can anybody recomend me better solution  killing for killing application than 
terminateProcess() ?

Comment: What is the result of `GetLastError`?

Comment: When I use GetLastError I always get 0x6

Answer (score 4):

Those process cannot be terminated because you have no priviledges to do so. You would have to execute your application with elevated priviledges for it to work. There is no other way.

Comment: I tried elevating but it doesnt help. I even tried to hit End Process button in task manager for a my process (with empty user name) and I get access denied error despite the fact I am administrator. All other system process which killing is harmfull 
for system I can terminate,  but those without username - no way. It s weird for me and i have no clue what is it all about

Comment: You may need to elevate yourself to SYSTEM privilege, not merely to Administrator privilege.  Try running the program using psexec -s and see if it works then.  Is the application is question launched from a conventional user account, or is it special?  Might there be a kernel-mode component protecting it, ala anti-virus software?