# How to kill a system process in C++

Tags: c++, process, kill

I have found an [example](http://www.2shared.com/file/SvmCL_p5/Exam28.html?) of how to kill a normal process, but it wont kill a system process. 
I don't want to kill a critical process, just a system process.

How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to kill a process but you haven't permissions? what is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [TerminateProcess doesnt work for verified process id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869347/terminateprocess-doesnt-work-for-verified-process-id).

Comment: The question is under-tagged: all the world isn't windows and the answer differs on other operating systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what system are you running.

In Windows, the documentation provided is ambiguous and can be different from a version to another.

In *nix family (Mac OS X, Linux,...), you have to manipulate kernel-level threads and close them, by sending a SIGKILL signal. However, I don't know if, even in root user, you can send them by your will.

Answer (score 0):

It is operating system specific. On a [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) system like Linux, you might use the [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) syscall.

However, any decent operating system with some authentication (like e.g. the notion of user id in Linux) will forbid you to kill a system process, because precisely system processes are somehow privileged (so they are precisely "system processes" to protect them to be killed by any random process).